# Linq expression required for grouping

Tags: linq

I have a list with class "A" having two properties qty and groupId.e.g.

```
      Qty    GroupId
       8         1
       2         2
       2         3 
       1         4
       3         5
```

I need to group this on a factor value.e.g. let factor value=4.On basis of this factor value  group looks like :

```
     Qty      GroupId
      4          1    -   group1
      4          1    -   group2
      2          2   -|
      2          3   -|   group3
      1          4   -|  
      3          5   -|   group4
```

I need a linq expression for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't catch the way you want to group. Could you give some more details on how you would like to group?

Comment: @Raphael Althaus : I am not able to group on basis of factor value.I am not writting my code here because it is simple group by clause as specified by tobias below.

Comment: @rajeshKumar ok : the question is : your groups are dependent on result ordering. Are your results always ordered by GroupId, or ?

Comment: You can't get more rows by doing a `GroupBy` (row 1 give two groups), looks like you need a previous step before grouping

Answer (score 0):

In general grouping in linq is done by calling the method GroupBy() with a lambdaexpression saying how to group.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx

```
// your list
IList<ClassA> listToGroup = new List<ClassA>(){ ... your items ...};
// Factor
int factor = 4;
// group the list by Qty value of the ClassA-items
var resultOfGrouping = listToGroup.GroupBy(a => a.Qty * factor == 8);
```

Hth Tobi

Comment: Thanks Tobias.Above query will return grouping on basis of qty.I need to group on basis of factor value.e.g.If you see above list then you can find that there is 8 qty in first item.Means it can be divided in two group if factor value is 4.i.e. why i divided it in two group with same group id.In 2nd and 3rd position,there is only two items,which make total 4 equal to factor value.so combined it makes group 3rd.respectively items at 4th and 5th position combined  forms group 4.Am i clear now ? Is this type of grouping possible in linq ?

Comment: Sorry I dont get your grouping algorithm. But generally you can use any algorithm for grouping. I updated my answer. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I am leaving my idea to implement this logic in linq.